# Enable inserting new rows but disable editing of existing ones in RadGridView

Tags: silverlight, telerik, radgridview

I need to allow users to add new entries to GridView but at the same to disallow editing of existing entries. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [IsReadOnlyBinding](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/p_telerik_windows_controls_gridview_gridviewdatacontrol_isreadonlybinding.html) property of a RadGridView, for example:

```
<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyViewModel.SomeData}" 
                     IsReadOnlyBinding="{Binding Path=IsExisting}" ... />
```

Each of your entries would then need to have a property named `IsExisting`, which has the value `true` if the entry is existing and `false` if it is new.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm correct, you can set the IsReadOnly property to be true so that the user cannot change existing entries on the grid.

However, you can always change the collection of data that the grid is binded to, in the code behind.

All you would have to do is add some new item to the collection, and then call Rebind on the grid. And your grid will be updated.

HTH